# вывод всех чисел со строки

Tags: c, строки, циклы, double

Доброго времени суток! В задаче сказано вывести все числа со строки.
Я считываю число x посредством atof и "перепрыгиваю" его с помощью sprintf в буфер который возвращает количество символов в числе x - потом меняю положение указателя. Условие для выхода из цикла есть. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем коренная проблема моего кода, который  вместо вывода всех вещественных чисел с введенной строки зацикленно печатает. Можно ли исправить этот фрагмент - или идея co sprintf изначально неправильна? Спасибо за внимание.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(void){

   char str[50];
   char buffer[50];
   double x;

   puts("enter a string: \n");
   fgets(str, 50, stdin);
   str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';

//print all doubles from string;

   char* strptr = str;

   while(*strptr != '\0'){
     if(isdigit(*strptr)){
        x = atof(strptr);
        printf("%f\n", x);

        strptr = strptr + (sprintf(buffer, "%f", x));
    }
    else strptr++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему можно увидеть, если запустить на выполнение следующую демонстрационную программу

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    double x = 1.2;
    char buffer[50];

    int n = sprintf(buffer, "%lf", x);
    puts(buffer);
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
1.200000
8
```

Как видно из вывода, выводимое число по количеству дробных знаков не соответствует исходному числу. В результате указатель может иметь не корректное значение в цикле.

Вместо используемого вами подхода лучше использовать подход на основе применения функции `strtod`, которая объявлена в заголовочном файле `<stdlib.h>` следующим образом

```
double strtod(const char * restrict nptr, char ** restrict endptr);
```

Ниже показана демонстрационная программа, которая использует эту функцию

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stype.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str[] = "abc1.2def34ghi54.78j";

    puts(str);

    for ( char *p = str; *p; )
    {
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)*p))
        {
            char *q;
            double x = strtod(p, &q);
            printf("%lf ", x);
            p = q;
        }
        else
        {
            ++p;
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
abc1.2def34ghi54.78j
1.200000 34.000000 54.780000
```

В свою программу вы также могли бы добавить проверку на наличие знака числа, то есть если встречается один из символов `'-'` или `'+'`, а за ним следует цифра. Вообще-то константы с плавающей точкой могут также задаваться в шестнадцатиричном формате,  но, думаю, вам это не нужно.